# When Git Merge Vs Git Override happen , while working with same file

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

This probably a very basic question but I didn't find any in the stack exchange where it is written with some examples and I got confused while seeing different results.

I want to understand below points only, if anyone can help me in understanding or guide me to a right documentation

1. I created 3 branch with File A, One is Master and then the other two is derived from master. Branch A and Branch B
2. Change the code (adding new lines of code not deleting any existing) in File A for Branch A and also the same is done in File A for Branch B
3. When I merge the code from Branch A to Master , it overrides the code which is fine
4. When I again merge the code from Branch B to master again it merged the code  (In branch B , I have added another set of lines in part of the code not the same as I did in Branch A). which I am not sure why it got merged ??
   Since I read in one documentation that if the parent branch where the code will merge is chnaged and also the source branch is chnaged, it should show as merge conflict.

   Does Merge conflict is only for the code conflict on the same line if anyone removed or added any more details ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two files with diffrent content on the same lines for example. So? Git don't know which one do you want to store then we got conflict to resolve. As you said, it's simple.